# How can I change the background-image of an option while creating it?

Tags: javascript, html, background-image, html-select

I'm creating an option in a select element and trying to change the background image.

```
nextItem = document.createElement('option');

nextItem.innerHTML = text;

nextItem.style.backgroundImage = "url(icons/add.png);";

nextItem.className = "class1";
```

When I use firebug, however, I can see that what actually gets created is this:

```
<option class="class1" style="">text</option>
```

Why is it creating the the style attribute but not putting any information in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the semi-colon in the url.

Change:

```
nextItem.style.backgroundImage = "url(icons/add.png);";
```

to:

```
nextItem.style.backgroundImage = "url(icons/add.png)";
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Vwu8m/)**

Answer (score 1):

You would try this `nextItem.style.backgroundImage = "url('icons/add.png')";`